# Select specific image in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Depending on which button the user touches in may App, I have to change a specific image from several visible ones. Before Jetpack Compose I used the binding IDs or findViewById. How should I do now? because since there is no inflate, I think there is no way to access an image via its ID, right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state should decide what image to choose.  So it should be a parameter to the composable function that generates the view.